# C ++ Inter Process Communication using redirected Input and Output not work with release build

Tags: c++, ipc

I'm working on a project which needed to create a child process and re-directed its input and output to the parent process.
I'm following this example on MSDN ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx)). Currently it works with debug build, but not release build. I can't figure it out why. Please help me
The coding of the child process as follow (very similar to the example):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <Iepmapi.h>
#include <Wininet.h>
#include <vector>

#define BUFSIZE 4096 
using namespace std;

vector<wstring> subStringByString(wstring input, wstring delimiter)
{
    int pos = input.find(delimiter);
    vector<wstring> arr;
    while (pos != wstring::npos)
    {
        wstring token = input.substr(0, pos);
        arr.push_back(token);
        input = input.substr(pos + delimiter.size(), input.size());
        pos = input.find(delimiter);
    }
    arr.push_back(input);
    return arr;
}

int main(void)
{
    WCHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
    HANDLE hStdin, hStdout;
    BOOL bSuccess;

    hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    if (
        (hStdout == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) ||
        (hStdin == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        )
        ExitProcess(1);

    // Send something to this process's stdout using printf.
    printf("\n ** This is a message from the child process. ** \n");

    // This simple algorithm uses the existence of the pipes to control execution.
    // It relies on the pipe buffers to ensure that no data is lost.
    // Larger applications would use more advanced process control.
    int rc = 0;
    for (;;)
    {
        // Read from standard input and stop on error or no data.
        bSuccess = ReadFile(hStdin, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
        wstring input = wstring(chBuf);
        wstring delimiter = L"  ";
        vector<wstring> arr = subStringByString(input, delimiter);

        int rc = 0;

        if (!bSuccess || dwRead == 0) 
            break;
        if (IESetProtectedModeCookie(arr[0].c_str(), arr[1].c_str(), arr[2].c_str(), INTERNET_COOKIE_THIRD_PARTY) != S_OK)
        {
            DWORD error = GetLastError();
            rc = -27;
        }
        // Write to standard output and stop on error.
        if (rc == 0 )
            bSuccess = WriteFile(hStdout, L"0", dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
        else 
            bSuccess = WriteFile(hStdout, L"-27", dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks,
Vinh

Parent process code:

```
std::wstring invoke(const std::wstring input)
{
    if (!CreateChildProcess())
        return L"error";
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
    WCHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE] ;
    const WCHAR* temp = input.c_str();
    wcscpy(chBuf, temp);
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    for (;;)
    {
        bSuccess = WriteFile(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, chBuf, dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess) break;
    }
    CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr);
    HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    for (;;)
    {
        bSuccess = ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess) break;

        bSuccess = WriteFile(hParentStdOut, chBuf, dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess) break;
    }
    //TerminateProcess(_processId, 0);
    return std::wstring(&chBuf[0]);
}

bool CreateChildProcess(void)
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
    // Set the bInheritHandle flag so pipe handles are inherited. 
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDIN. 
    if (!CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_IN_Rd, &g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, &saAttr, 0))
        return false;
    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
    {
        cleanUpHandle();
        return false;
    }
    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT.
    if (!CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0))
    {
        cleanUpHandle();
        return false;
    }
    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
    {
        cleanUpHandle();
        return false;
    }

    // Create a child process that uses the previously created pipes for STDIN and STDOUT.
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;
    STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
    // Set up members of the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure. 
    ZeroMemory(&piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    // Set up members of the STARTUPINFO structure. 
    // This structure specifies the STDIN and STDOUT handles for redirection.
    ZeroMemory(&siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;
    siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    // Create the child process. 
    HANDLE hToken = NULL;
    HANDLE hNewToken = NULL;
    bSuccess = OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),
        TOKEN_DUPLICATE |
        TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT |
        TOKEN_QUERY |
        TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY,
        &hToken);

    if (!bSuccess) {
        return 0;
    }
    hNewToken = CreateLowLevelToken(hToken);
    wa_wstring deploymentPath;
    if (WAAPI_FAILED(ProcessUtils::getDeploymentPath(deploymentPath)))
    {
        return false;
    }
    wa_wstring path = deploymentPath + wa_wstring(PROCESS_PATH);

    LPTSTR szCmdline = wstring_to_LPTSTR(path);
    if (_processId != 0)
    {
        TerminateProcess(_processId, 0);
    }

    TCHAR szCmdline2[] = PROCESS_PATH;
    bSuccess = CreateProcessAsUser(hNewToken, NULL, szCmdline2, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &siStartInfo, &piProcInfo);

    DWORD error = GetLastError();
    if (!bSuccess)
    {
        cleanUpHandle();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        _processId = piProcInfo.dwProcessId;
        CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Turn on all compiler warnings, this is a typical symptom of undefined behaviour somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
In "debug build, the value of **dwRead**, **dwWritten** are trash value, however, the value of those in relase build are 0. Which cause the parent hang.
To fix this :

```
DWORD dwRead = -1, dwWritten = -1;
```